# Wordpress Custom Uploader not showing Attachment Settings

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been looking all over for this and haven't found anything related to this.

I am using a custom uploader in a plugin to insert an image.

The code I am using is this

```
$('#upload_image_button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
    if (custom_uploader) {
        custom_uploader.open();
        return;
    }
    //Extend the wp.media object
    custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Choose Image',
        button: {
            text: 'Choose Image'
        },
        multiple: false
    });
    //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
    custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
        attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        console.log(attachment);
        $('.ppwfg-images td').append( "<div id='image-placeholders' style='width:75px; height:75px; margin: 3px; float: left;'>" );
        $('#image-placeholders').append( "<input type='text' id='upload_image' name='ppwfg[]' class='' value=''  size='10' hidden />" );
        $('#image-placeholders').append( "<img src='' id='upload_image_holder' class='ppwfg_image' style='width:75px; height:75px; margin: 3px;'/>" );
        $('#image-placeholders').append( "<a class='close-overlay remove'>x</a>" );

        $('#image-placeholders').attr("id", attachment.id);

        $('#upload_image').attr("value", attachment.url);
        $('#upload_image').attr("class", attachment.id);
        $('#upload_image').attr("id", attachment.id);

        $('#upload_image_holder').attr("src", attachment.url);
        $('#upload_image_holder').attr("class", attachment.id);
        $('#upload_image_holder').attr("id", attachment.id);
    });
    //Open the uploader dialog
    custom_uploader.open();
});
```

The uploader opens and I can choose an image and insert it but the problem is it always uses the main image, and does not show the attachment settings with the drop down to choose which image to use... So I am left with the default image which ends up being to big.

How do I display the attachment settings in the media.frame?

Answer (score 0):

Too old but thought I'd answer for some one still looking.

```
custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Choose Image',
        button: {
            text: 'Choose Image'
        },
        frame: 'post',
        state:    'insert',
        multiple: false
    });

    //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
    custom_uploader.on('insert', function() {
```

You can select frame:post but then you've to select the state:insert and use the function custom_uploader.on('insert',function(){